# Install jpeg module in ubuntu

Tags: python

I am working on an image compression module, for that I want use jpeg library, but when I am importing it I am getting the following error.

```
"" import jpeg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jpeg
```

this was happening after i installed the libjpeg library also, I want use jpeg in python image compression, so can any tell me resolve the problem , how to install jpeg in ubuntu
and help me solve the error .

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's recommended to use the Python Imaging Library as the jpeg module is deprecated since python 3.0. So the module you need to import:

```
import Image
```

If you still get an import error then try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

Documentation can be found here: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm
and there are some jpeg examples on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to use the `jpeg` module in an unsupported platform. According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/jpeg.html) it's only supported in IRIX, so if you try to import it in a different platform, then you'll get the `ImportError` exception.