# Python reading a .jpg file in binary for beginner

Tags: python, binary, jpeg, exif

I'm trying to learn more about exif data contained within a photo. What I don't understand is why I get the result from the following code:

```
file = open("IMG.JPG", "rb")
print(file.read(2))
print(file.read(2))
```

Gives me a result of:

```
>>>
b'\xff\xd8'
b'\xff\xe1'
```

Why are they different? The first result line makes sense, FFD8 represent that its a jpeg.

Comment: When I read the very first two lines in a book, I get the title and author. Why are the next two lines different from the first two?

Comment: So once i do file.read(2) i cant re-read those 2 lines?

Comment: Yep. You can't use `read` again straight after another one.

Comment: Well, you *can*. It’s just that `read` automatically moves the seek pointer forward. You can do `file.seek(0)` to go back to the beginning.

Comment: getting ahead a bit maybe, but you really don't want to directly read the raw jpg file data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566655/install-jpeg-module-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because each time you call file.read(x) it reads the *next* x items, not the *first* x items.

Answer (score 1):

`file.read` will move on to the next part to read once you call it. If you read it to the end, and call it again, it would return nothing.

For example, i have a file called `test.txt`, like this:

```
abcdefg
hijklmn
```

Let's try to read it:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read(7)
    data2 = f.read()


>>> data
'abcdefg'
>>> data2
'\nhijklmn'
```

See?

Now, if you want to get the same thing twice, you can make the reading back to the beginning using `file.seek`:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read(7)
    f.seek(0)
    data2 = f.read(7)


>>> data
'abcdefg'
>>> data2
'abcdefg'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you read() you move the file pointer.  If you want to read the same thing repeatedly (why?) then you can use

```
filename.seek(0)
```

to rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the file.